# How to write a specific Bessel function in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, special-functions

I want to plot the following function on Mathematica, and I gave it a go on wolframalpha.

Bessel[n,z] is the usual form, but I am not sure how to use this to compute the following plot:

\begin{equation}
u(r,t)=\frac{\alpha J_{4}(i\sqrt{2}r)}{J_{4}\big(\frac{100*2}{\alpha}\big)}e^{-16t^2}
\end{equation}

I tried

```
BesselJ[4, I Sqrt[2] x]/BesselJ[4, 200]
```

But I don't know how to include the zeros defined by $\alpha$

Any help appreciated!

where $\alpha$ are the zeros of the Bessel function.

Comment: By "zeros of *the* Bessel function," do you mean `alpha = BesselJZero[n, k]`? For `n = 4` for `k = 1, 2, 3,....`?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

u[x_, t_, α_] := α*BesselJ[4, I Sqrt[2] x]/BesselJ[4, 200/α]*
  E^(-16 t^2)

u[x, t, α] == -u[x, t, -α]

(* True *)

u[x, t, α] == u[x, -t, α]

(* True *)

u[x, t, α] == u[-x, t, α]

(* True *)

Manipulate[
 Plot3D[u[x, t, α],
  {x, -5, 5}, {t, -2, 2},
  AxesLabel -> Automatic,
  ClippingStyle -> None],
 {{α, 1}, 0.05, 5, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** For `α = BesselJZero[4, k]`

```
Manipulate[
 α = BesselJZero[4, k];
 Plot3D[u[x, t, α], {x, -5, 5}, {t, -2, 2},
  AxesLabel -> Automatic,
  ClippingStyle -> None,
  PlotLabel -> StringForm["α = `` = ``", α, α // N],
  WorkingPrecision -> 15],
 {{k, 1}, Range[10], ControlType -> SetterBar}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bob, see relevant post! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4454884/solving-an-ivbp-for-a-metal-rod-dipped-from-cold-to-warm-water?noredirect=1#comment9332552_4454884